# что за синяя кружка появилась в Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Все работало, работало и вдруг на тебе новость!!

[image: синие кружки]

что за синяя кружка появилась в Android Studio?

и как это исправить?

Comment: Это чистая библиотека Java, вот тут спрашивали об этом:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248629/what-do-the-module-icons-mean-in-android-studio

Comment: еще вчера она была нормальной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

уф прошло, кружки являются во время обновления Gradle в другом проекте.